# Ionic tab content with vertical tabs along left side

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I am using ionic in my application, and I am able to use horizontal tabs perfectly.
Is it possible to have vertical tabs, something like below

[image]

Comment: I think you can just override some CSS. Look in the Ionic/scss/_tabs.scss for how its currently done

Comment: @devqon I am not able to understand. Can you help ? Moreover I am not using scss. I have to override in css only

Comment: You can play around with this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myrZwQ. Add a class tabs-left or something to the tabs and apply CSS rules

Answer (score 0):

```
#filter-tab-section ion-tab-button {
    background-color: rgb(241, 243, 246);
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
}
#filter-tab-section ion-tab-bar {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: contents;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.